# Kotlin Android oauth2 token request only returning errors

Tags: android, api, kotlin, oauth-2.0, retrofit2

I am working on an user app for a local charitable organization, and need to access their API.  The API is from wild apricot, and this is the documentation for making a token request:

Authentication tokens are obtained from Wild Apricot's authentication service, which is located at https://oauth.wildapricot.org. This service adheres to oAuth 2.0.

This is the access option I need to implement:

-----------------In order to obtain access token with API key, you have to make the following request:

> POST /auth/token HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: oauth.wildapricot.org
>
> Authorization: Basic BASE64_ENCODED("APIKEY:YOUR_API_KEY")
>
> Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> grant_type=client_credentials&scope=auto

-------------------------------So. finally your request will look like:

> POST /auth/token HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: oauth.wildapricot.org
>
> Authorization: Basic QVBJS0VZOm85c2U4N3Jnb2l5c29lcjk4MDcwOS0=
>
> Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> grant_type=client_credentials&scope=auto

I am attempting to make this call with retrofit2, and an okhttp3 interceptor, and getting a bad request response (I am very much new and learning, and have not been able to get anything other response than a 400 bad request (when I use "/auth/token" as the endpoint), or a 404 not found (when I use "/auth/token HTTP/1.1" as the endpoint).  If someone could tell me where exactly I am messing this up It would be greatly appreciated, the code I have tried is below.

**Interface:**

```
interface WAApiCall {
@POST("auth/token")
fun callPost(@Body body:String ): Call<AuthToken>
}
```

**Call Service:**

```
object WAApiCallService {

private const val API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxIxHavexAxValidxKeyxxxx"
private const val BASE_URL = "https://oauth.wildapricot.org/"
private val AUTH = "Basic" + Base64.encodeToString(API_KEY.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP) 
private const val CONTENT_TYPE = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
private var api:WAApiCall? = null

private fun getWAApi(context: Context) : WAApiCall {

    if(api==null){
        val OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC

        OkHttpClient.addInterceptor{chain ->
           
            val request = chain.request()
            Log.d("CALL", request.body.toString())
            
            val newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Host", "oauth.wildapricot.org")
                .addHeader("Authorization", AUTH ) 
                .addHeader("Content-type", CONTENT_TYPE)
                .method(request.method, request.body)
                .build()
            chain.proceed(newRequest)
        }

        api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(OkHttpClient.build())
            .build()
            .create(WAApiCall::class.java)
    }

    return api!!

}


fun call(context: Context) =
    getWAApi(context)
}
```

**Function in Main Activity to make the call:**

```
fun testRequest(){
val call = WAApiCallService.call(this)
call.callPost("grant_type=client_credentials&scope=auto")
    .enqueue(object: Callback<AuthToken>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuthToken>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("FAILURE", t.localizedMessage)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuthToken>, response: Response<AuthToken>) {
            Log.i("SUCCESS", "TOKEN = ${response.body().toString()}")
            Log.i("SUCCESS", "${response}")
            val token = response.body()?.accessToken
            Log.i("SUCCESS", "TOKEN = $token")
        }
    })
}
```

**Error message:**

> ```
> I/SUCCESS: TOKEN = null
> I/SUCCESS: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request,   url=https://oauth.wildapricot.org/auth/token}
> ```

I think that I am just not understanding how to implement this type of request in some basic way, I could not get it to work in Postman either.  I understand that I need to send the credentials to the authentication server, and receive an access token, that will expire and need to be refreshed, and that It will be included in each actual API endpoint call, I guess I'm just missing something crucial in the most important step of that process (getting the actual token, I am imagining it is a simple, forehead slapping kind of misunderstanding on my part?).  The wild apricot API is on swagger hub, and I am able to gain access through that UI, with my API key, and see the responses, so I know that it is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client credentials request looks mostly all good. The only thing I can see that looks wrong is no space character in the AUTH header between 'Basic' and the encoded credential.

If that doesn't work, could you [trace the HTTP request](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/21/android-https-debugging) and verify that you are sending the message you think you are.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for that observation, it led me to figuring out what ultimately was wrong in my initial attempt. After adding that space, I traced the request and found that It was actually sending two headers for content type.

The fix for that was to set the header in the retrofit call from the interface:

```
interface WAApiCall {
@POST("auth/token")
fun callPost(@Body Body: okhttp3.RequestBody, @Header("Content-type") type: String): Call<AuthToken>
}
```

As you can see the body is also slightly different, the call was getting through but was returning:

> "unsupported_grant_type".

I was passing a raw string as the body parameter, which was including the quotation marks in the request.  The solution there was to pass the okhttp3.Request body type rather than a raw string, in the function that makes the actual call it looks like this:

```
val body: "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=auto&obtain_refresh_token=true"
val requestBody = RequestBody.create("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull(),body)
val call = WAApiCallService.call(this)
call.callPost(requestBody,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .enqueue(object: Callback<AuthToken>{
```

With those changes the call succeeds and my long running headache is over.